# Logback write OutOfMemoryError to a file?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, logback

I would like to be able to capture OutOfMemoryError and write it to a file. Currently logback only puts it into the console.

**How can I configure logback to write into a file without explicitly capturing the Error and calling log.error() myself?**

Since it is hard to predict a place of occurrence of such an error it would be best to 'bind' an file appender to the console appender. Though how could it be done?

For the same of completeness this is the current configuration I am using:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %thread | %highlight(%-5level) | %cyan(%logger{1}) | %method | %line | %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>${STDOUT_LOG_LEVEL}</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE_ALL" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>.\Hub_logs\%d{yyyy-MM,aux}\%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_all.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <if condition='p("NUMBER_OF_DAYS_TO_KEEP").matches("^-?\\d+$")'>
            <then>
                <if condition='Integer.parseInt(p("NUMBER_OF_DAYS_TO_KEEP")) &lt; 0'>
                    <then>
                        <maxHistory>0</maxHistory>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <maxHistory>${NUMBER_OF_DAYS_TO_KEEP}</maxHistory>
                    </else>
                </if>
            </then>
            <else>
                <maxHistory>0</maxHistory>
            </else>
        </if>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches given value -->
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>250MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %method | %line | %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>${FILE_ALL_LOG_LEVEL}</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_ALL"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Logback is not putting it on the console appender. The JVM is writing it out (via something like System.err.println). I've tried http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j/ and no luck for OutOfMemoryErrors.